# The background color of the listview is not changing. How do I fix it?

Tags: android

I'm using this code

```
ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView idno = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idno);
            TextView fullname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fullname);
            TextView remark = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.remark);
            new DisplayStudent().execute("Update", idno.getText().toString());
            if(remark.getText().toString().equals("absent")) {
                if(isStudentLate) {
                    view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorLate));
                    fullname.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    remark.setText("late");
                }
                else {
                    view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPresent));
                    fullname.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    remark.setText("present");
                }
            }
            else if(remark.getText().toString().equals("present") || remark.getText().toString().equals("late")) {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                fullname.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                remark.setText("absent");
            }
        }
    });
    ((BaseAdapter)getListView().getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Everytime I tap on an item, the background color of the item I tapped is supposed to change. Why does it not change? I tried removing the `((BaseAdapter)getListView().getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();` it does change but when I scroll down and scroll up again it goes back to its original background color.

For example. One Item's background color is colored white. When I tap that item, it changed to green. That's perfect. But when I scroll down and scroll up again, the item that I tapped changed back to white. How do I fix this?

Comment: This is because list view reuses its views. You have to maintain a seperate array  or hashMap for students for whether they are present or absent. And then use this info in getView of your listAdapter to inflate views accordingly.

Comment: Like frosty said Listview recycle it´s rows. .Refactor your code to change the background color in Adapter.getView method according to you selection...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this in your ListView tag:

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

And also try this:

```
android:background="color code here"
```